# Работа с большими массивами. Сортировка

Tags: php, массивы

Всем привет, я новичок в PHP, поэтому не судите строго. 
Имею такой массив:

```
  0 => '2018-08-26 17:16:49',
  1 => 'Сет белый соус ',
  2 => 'Суши Гункан креветка спайси',
  3 => 'Контейнер ПРС-19',
  4 => 'Соус соевый 40 гр',

  5 => '2018-08-15 21:24:41',
  6 => 'Сет На двоих белый соус',

  7 => '2018-08-12 18:31:44',
  8 => 'Red hot 5  шт спайси соус',
  9 => 'Суши Гункан креветка спайси',
  10 => 'Соус соевый 40 гр',
  11 => 'Пакет',
  12 => 'Палочки бамбуковые',
  13 => 'Контейнер ПРС-19',
  14 => 'Ланч бокс LBS-1 (маленький)',
  15 => 'Калифорния люкс креветка',

  16 => '2018-07-17 17:31:56',
  17 => 'Суши Гункан креветка спайси',
  18 => 'Red hot 5  шт спайси соус',
  19 => 'Каприз креветка',
  20 => 'Вулкан креветка спайси соус 5шт',
  21 => 'Пакет',
  22 => 'Палочки бамбуковые',
  23 => 'Соус соевый 40 гр',
  24 => 'Контейнер ПРС-19',
  25 => 'Ланч бокс LBE-1  (большой)' .... итд
```

Как мне разделить этот массив по дате? Идет дата допустим, а потом заказы(до следующий даты). Ну я вот визуально показал. Все это мне нужно будет записать в в базу.

Вот код:

```
foreach($res['customersDeliveryHistory'] as $key=> $val)
{
    foreach($val['deliveryHistory'] as $key => $vals)
    {
        $items[] = $vals['date'];
        foreach($vals['items'] as $key => $eda)
        {
            $items[] = $eda['name'];
        }
    }
}
```

Мне нужно, чтобы массив стал таким:

```
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => '2018-08-26 17:16:49',
    1 => 'Сет белый соус',
    2 => 'Суши гункан'

  ),
  1 => (
  array(
    0 => '2018-08-15 21:56:12',
    .......
```

Comment: *Все это мне нужно будет записать в в базу.* База (вернее, таблица в базе данных) - это несортированная куча. Так что записывайте как есть, в любом порядке. Никакие заморочки с сортировками на результат не влияют (если не считать зря потраченного на сортировку времени).

Comment: @Akina мне потом эти заказы нужно выводить как раз таки по дате, если я все кучей запишу, то это не поможет мне.

Comment: Индекс на таблице по нужному полю и сортировка при выводе. *это не поможет мне* Если Вам пишут ответ (пусть и как комментарий) - то, наверное, не на пустом месте...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Если $key нигде не используется - не пишите его, не захламляйте код
foreach($res['customersDeliveryHistory'] as $val)
{
    foreach($val['deliveryHistory'] as $vals)
    {
        $data = [
            $vals['date'],
        ];
        foreach($vals['items'] as $eda)
        {
            $data[] = $eda['name'];
        }
        $items[] = $data;
    }
}
print_r($items);
```

Или еще проще:

```
foreach($res['customersDeliveryHistory'] as $val)
{
    foreach($val['deliveryHistory'] as $vals)
    {
        $items[] = array_merge(
            [$vals['date']],
            array_column($vals['items'], 'name')
        );
    }
}
print_r($items);
```